# How Tokenizer pattern works with NLTK

Tags: nltk

I have a dataset that is composed of a set of texts.
These texts must be cleaned since they are extracts from the **Reddit** forum or **Twitter**.

The idea is to keep only the basic words from these texts. For example, I would like to not consider the numbers, the words that have the "_" symbol in it, and the words that contain numbers in it.

I have the constraint to use only the `NLTK` library, and Numpy also of course.

So I think I should use the Tokenizer from this library to clean my data, but I need documentation/help, to understand how to define the pattern to do such a cleanup.

**Anyone can help me, please?**

So far I did try this piece of code:

```
tokenizer1 = RegexpTokenizer('\d+|\d')
tokenizer2 = RegexpTokenizer('\w+')
```

What I understand:

**tokenizer1: considers only the numbers,**

**tokenizer2: considers strings until the next whitespace, so this still includes the numbers.**

> My idea was to do the difference between the result from tokenizer1
>   and tokenizer2 to remove the numbers.

This seems working, but I do not know how to manage more difficult aspects, such as not considering words that contain numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the standard word tokenizer and then filter the tokens as follows:

```
import nltk
s = "some words contain numbers for example af345ed and l00p."
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(s)

def isWordContainingNumber(w):
    if any([c.isdigit() for c in w]) and any([c.isdigit() for c in w]):
        return(True)
    return(False)

print([t for t in tokens if isWordContainingNumber(t)])
#['af345ed', 'l00p']
print([t for t in tokens if not isWordContainingNumber(t)])
#['some', 'words', 'contain', 'numbers', 'for', 'example', 'and', '.']
```